# Nginx Execute Multiple Location Blocks

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx `location` block:

```
location ^~ /publish {
  allow 127.0.0.1;

  #Allow home
  allow 99.100.101.102;

  deny all;
}
```

Then this `location` block to process PHP after:

```
location ~\.php {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

The problem is that files inside of `/publish` like `execute.php` aren't being processed by the fastcgi PHP processor, they simply output the pure PHP code when called from CURL. How do I enforce the security rules defined in the `/publish` block but also still execute the PHP block if the file ends in .php?

Answer (score 5):

nginx only applies one `location` block to a request.

Use `include` if you'd like to share directives between blocks, or a `try_files` pointing to an `@php` location if you'd like to point multiple PHP-using `location` blocks to a single PHP handling `location`.

Comment: Shane, would you mind doing a gist or pastebin? Obviously I want to execute the PHP fastcgi block only if the file ends in `.php`, so how do I apply that location rule?

Comment: @Justin You'll need to provide some more context about your configuration.  Do you have multiple different location blocks that you want to run PHP code in?

Comment: Yes, multiple location blocks, which may contain PHP files.